# How can I update a changing value in Powershell in a web.config file?

Tags: powershell, config

I am trying to update text inside a web.config file with powershell, but I am having a very, very difficult time.

The problem is this line

```
<add key="Models.Catalog.Repository" value=Server23 />
```

You see where the Server23 is? this value sometimes can be empty, which will be represented as "" or sometimes it can have a different name like "\Server25\path"

How do I tell PowerShell to replace/insert data if the field is empty/has some text in it?

here is the full code

```
 $GP_AP= "Server1"
 $NewMD = "\\JohnWick"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $GP_AP  -ScriptBlock  {
    
    $date= Get-Date -Format "dd_MM_yyyy_HHMM_ss"
    $webfile = "C:\Program Files\TEST\IIS\Web.config"
    
    (Copy-Item -Path $webfile -Destination $webfile_Test_$Date)
    
    #[xml]$webconfigfile = Get-Content "C:\Program Files\TEST\IIS\Web.config"
    #[xml]$2 = Get-Content "\\Server1\C$\Program Files\TEST\IIS\Web.config"
    
    $olddata = "*"

    #(Get-Content $webfile -raw).Replace("<add key=`"Models.Catalog.Repository`" value=$olddata />","<add key=`"Models.Catalog.Repository`" value=$Using:NewMD />") `
     #| Set-Content "C:\Program Files\TEST\IIS\Web.config" -Force -Encoding UTF8 -ErrorAction Stop
    
    (Get-Content $webfile -raw).Replace('<add key="Models.Catalog.Repository" value=Server23 />',"<add key=`"Models.Catalog.Repository`" value=$Using:NewMD />") `
     | Set-Content "C:\Program Files\TEST\IIS\Web.config" -Force -Encoding UTF8 -ErrorAction Stop
 
    } # end of script block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path        = '\\server\c$\Program Files\TEST\IIS\web.config'

[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw

$stuffIwant  = "\\Blah-244"

$config.SelectNodes("//add[@key='Models.Catalog.Repository']") | `  
ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("value", $stuffIwant) }

$config.Save($path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below will allow you to set values in a web config's `<appSettings>` based on key names. All the nodes must exist. This script will not create them. You'll obviously need to edit the script's default params.

```bsh
param(
    [string] $pathToWebConfig = "$PSScriptRoot\web.config"

    [System.Collections.Hashtable] $appSettings = @{ 
        someKey = 'somevalue'; 
        someOtherKey = 'someOtherValue' 
    }
)

function UpdateXmlConfigAppSettings(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $configFilePath,

    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [System.Collections.Hashtable] $appSettingsDict 
) {
    [xml] $webConfig = Get-Content $configFilePath
    foreach($key in $appSettingsDict.Keys) {
        $node = $webConfig.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings/add[@key = '$key']")
        if ($null -ne $node) {
            $node.SetAttribute('value', $appSettingsDict[$key])
        }
        else {
            throw "$appSettingsDict[$key] is not a valid key in AppSettings"
        }
    }
    $webConfig.Save($configFilePath)
}

UpdateXmlConfigAppSettings -configFilePath $pathToWebConfig -appSettingsDict $appSettings
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, I have tried this but had some errors with parameters, but anyhow, I have found the answer to my question, will paste code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PowerShell code I've used in an Azure Pipeline, to update one of my config settings.

```
$fileName = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Artifacts/MikesServices/Web.config";
$newValue = "MIKES_NEW_SERVER_001"

Write-Host "Patching file: $fileName"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $fileName
$oldValue = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//appSettings/add[@key="ServerName"]/@value').value
$xml.SelectSingleNode('//appSettings/add[@key="ServerName"]/@value').value = $newValue
$xml.Save($fileName);

Write-Host "Changed setting from ""$oldValue"" to ""$newValue"""
```

This bit of code would update a setting like this, in my *web.config* file.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ServerName" value="MIKES_SERVER_001" />
  </appSettings>
```

And the output looks something like this:

```
2023-12-14T10:10:04 Patching file: C:\azagent\A1\_work\r4\a/_Artifacts/MikesServices/Web.config
2023-12-14T10:10:04 Changed setting from "true" to "false"
```